# Manage spinners with same data while performing OnItemSelectedListener in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, baseadapter, onitemselectedlistener

I have 5 spinners. I am using `BaseAdapter` to set custom row on spinners. I am loading the same data i.e. ArrayList of the model in each `Spinner`.

Now, the problem is, when I select an item from any spinner, the selected item should disappear from other spinners. Or, if I deselect it or change the previously selected item with another, then it should reappear in other spinners.

Below is my code

```
class ConsumerPreferencesActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var mainList: ArrayList<Cuisine>
    private lateinit var selectedList: ArrayList<Cuisine>
    private lateinit var displayList: ArrayList<Cuisine>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        mainList = ArrayList()
        displayList = ArrayList()
        selectedList = ArrayList()

        for (i in 1..5) {
            selectedList.add(Cuisine())
        }
        mainList.add(Cuisine())     //for empty first row
        displayList.add(Cuisine())  //for empty first row

        cuisinesSpinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>, selectedItemView: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedList[0] = displayList[position]
                doIterate()
            }
        }

        cuisinesSpinner2.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>, selectedItemView: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedList[1] = displayList[position]
                doIterate()
            }
        }

        cuisinesSpinner3.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>, selectedItemView: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedList[2] = displayList[position]
                doIterate()
            }
        }

        cuisinesSpinner4.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>, selectedItemView: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedList[3] = displayList[position]
                doIterate()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>) {
            }
        }

        cuisinesSpinner5.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>, selectedItemView: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedList[4] = displayList[position]
                doIterate()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun doIterate() {
        displayList.clear()
        displayList.addAll(mainList)

        for (c in selectedList) {

            for (d in mainList) {

                if (c.name != null) {
                    if (c.name == d.name) {
                        displayList.remove(c)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("TAG", "DATA")
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: I think you should maintain separate list for each spinner and create a `hashmap` which will keep selected item with respective spinner name. So that next time when you populate list for any spinner you will know which items to remove.